# Show full json set in Angular Material Autocomplete dropdown result on focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, autocomplete, angular-material

I am filtering a json file into an Angular Material Autocomplete search input; I can't seem to recreate the automatic dropdown with all the json elements on focus from the demo:  [Angular Material Demo Autocomplete](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete)

Here's my code so far :

HTML:

```
<md-autocomplete
  md-search-text="searchText"
  md-items="item in items | filter:searchText"              
  md-item-text="item.companyName + space + item.stockSymbol" 
  placeholder="Type Company Name or Stock Symbol">
  <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{ item.companyName }} {{ item.stockSymbol }}</span>
</md-autocomplete>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {  
 $scope.items = stocks.DowJones30;
 $scope.searchText = '';
 $scope.space = " ";  
}]);
```

the JSON bit goes like this:

```
var stocks={DowJones30:[{companyName:"3M",stockSymbol:"MMM"},
 {companyName:"American Express",stockSymbol:"AXP"},
 {companyName:"Apple",stockSymbol:"AAPL"},
//etc etc....
{companyName:"Wal-Mart",stockSymbol:"WMT"}]};
```

Full Code on Codepen:

[Angular Material Autocomplete](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/mOyEWy?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little reduction of the original example I found out that this line in the HTML is required for the Autocomplete to automatically drop down and show all the items, hope this helps someone else.

```
md-min-length="0"
```